# How do I make selectable A tag?

Tags: css, firefox, hyperlink, firefox-addon, xul

Is there any way to make the text within an `<a>` tag selectable, using CSS?

I can't seem to be able to search this query for useful results on the web, "a" just finds the word "a" :)

I don't control the original creation of the document.

Comment: Do you mean the text wrapped in anchor tags or an attribute (such as `href`)?

Comment: I think you're stuck with binding the `mouseup()` event and using `event.preventDefault()` if `window.getSelection` ( or its variants ) returns a value

Comment: The text *is* selectable by the user. He just needs to know how to do that. And you cannot change that with CSS; this is about functionality, and CSS is about presentational suggestions. Please describe first what the problem is, then why you would specifically use CSS to solve it. Does the tag “firefox” mean that you would be happy with a Firefox-only solution, or that Firefox is somehow essential to the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is specific to a Firefox feature.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this in a XUL document?

If so, you're probably looking for the following CSS property:

```
-moz-user-select: text;
```

I've used that on "description" elements with success but never tried on an "a" element.

Answer (score 0):

You're either literally trying to just select text inside of an anchor element as a user.

OR

You're trying to use JavaScript to select text inside an anchor for the purposes of utilizing that text.

If it's the first simply select the text just at the edge outside of the anchor, if the selected character is 49% of less closer to the anchor then the browser won't select that character.

If you're trying to use JavaScript to get the text of an anchor you'll want to look at my tutorial, try selecting text and then clicking on the anchor below. That should give you some much needed direction...

http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/javascript-parentnode-of-selected-text

If none of that helps it would greatly benefit yourself as well everyone else reading your question to communicate your goal with greater clarity.

Answer (score -1):

The nature of `<a>` is a link on HTML.So when mouse clicked on the text inside `<a>` the trigger of the link automatically triggered. I think it could not archive just by CSS alone. JavaScript need here

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doclick();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

may let you select the text and handle click (if necessary )

Comment: I think you mean mousedown. I would like to do this in css if possible.

Comment: Sry yes I meant mousedown. But IMO when <a> tag was used then mousedown already triggred the click event except cases that you nullify the effect of click by use href="javascript:void(0)". Then use CSS to make pointer become text selector. This was my only known solution ^.^.

Comment: I meant selecting text within `<a>`, not just the cursor.